# Failed to fill 2nd drop down list with getJSON and php

Tags: php, mysql, getjson, html-select

I have 2 drop down lists that gets their data from a database. I want depending on the value I choose on the first drop down (**#id_univ**) to appear corresponding values ​​in the second drop down.

The function I created is as follows:

```
$("#id_univ").on("change", function(){

                $.getJSON("ajax/univ_department.php",{university: $(this).val(), ajax: 'true'}, function(data){
                    var options = '';

                    for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
                        options += '<option value="' + data[i].id_dpt + '">' + data[i].nameDpt + '</option>';
                    }
                    $("#uni_departments").html(options);
                })
            })
```

With firebug Ι checked that returns the correct values ​​as I expected:

```
[{id_dpt: 1, nameDpt: 'Physics'},{id_dpt: 2, nameDpt: 'Mathematics'}]
```

But I don't see any value at the 2nd drop down (**#uni_departments**).

Any idea on what I'm doing wrong.

**UPDATE**

I just try the above code with jquery-1.2.3 and works fine. When I use the jquery-1.8.3, which is the default version that I'm using to my project it breaks.

Any suggestion where the problem may be, because I don't like to use older jquery!

Comment: Your code works fine for me. Are you sure that your html says `<select id='uni_departments'>`? Maybe just a typo? Did you put '#' in the id in your HTML, like `<select id='#uni_departments'>`?

Comment: No my html code is simple: `<select id="uni_departments"></select>`

Comment: `on` function added in jQuery-1.7. How could your code run on jquery-1.2.3, huh?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would try to use jquery's dom manipulation mechanism:

```
 $.getJSON("ajax/univ_department.php",{university: $(this).val(), ajax: 'true'}, function(data){
  $("#uni_departments").empty();
  for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    var opt = $('<option value="' + data[i].id_dpt + '">' + data[i].nameDpt + '</option>');
    $("#uni_departments").append(opt);
  }
})
```

Comment: Thanks I use your way, and I also change the format of the JSON results that I get back from `ajax/univ_department.php` and it works!